# define variable internal for get him in child window wpf-c#

Tags: c#, wpf

i have in the main window variable

example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   internal int i;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and i want to use him in child window and for that i do him internal (the two window in the same namespace) and the child window still doesn't recognize the variable

what i'm suppose to do?

Comment: Are you saying you want the two windows to _share_ the `i` variable or you want to access the _parent_ `i` variable from the _child_ window?

Comment: i want the two window share the i variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a public property on the child window of type `int`.  When you create the child window then set that property based on the value of the field in the parent window.

It appears that you want to be able to not just read the variable in the child class, but also modify it and have that change reflected in the parent form, so that will complicate the answer.

We'll need to start off with a helper class.  Because the data we're interested in is an `int` (which is a value type) we'll need something that is a reference type (i.e. a class).

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

So we'll start by not having an integer in the parent form, but instead an instance of this class:

```
public class Form1
{
    private Wrapper<int> data = new Wrapper<int>(); //TODO give better name
    //...
}
```

Next we'll need a public property on the child form; rather than an `int` we'll use this new class:

```
public class Form2
{
    public Wrapper<int> Data { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Now when we create the child class we'll set the property based on the value in the parent class:

```
public void someMethod()
{
    Form2 childForm = new Form2();
    childForm.Data = data;
    childForm.Show();
}
```

Now that we've done all this we've ensure that both the parent and child class have a reference to the same instance of `Wrapper`, so any changes to the `Value` property of the `Wrapper` instance (from either class) will be "seen" by either reference.

Comment: I would actually try and avoid sharing state like that if at all possible.

Comment: @ChaosPandion For what reason?  And how would you prefer to share state?

Comment: You now have two storage locations that represent the same data and one might become stale.

Comment: @ChaosPandion It's appropriate in most cases, as long as the child doesn't need to be setting the variable as well.  In the rarer cases where there is intermingled reading and writing between both forms you can use something more complicated, i.e. wrapping it in a reference type.  I agree this doesn't cover all cases, just the most common ones.

Comment: i want to change the variable in the main window from the child not to create from him a new one!

Comment: @user1657074 Well, that's a fairly significant change to the question, but I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Apparently, a while later, the OP decided he does need the more complex example.  Do you approve of the update answer?

Comment: in shortly we just need two variables one in form1, second in form 2 that both of them point on the same place (in our case on the new wrapper<int>();)